# Starting external application inside Java

Tags: java, javafx, processbuilder

I'm having trouble starting an application from my JavaFX GUI. I'm using `ProcessBuilder`. It creates the process, but the application won't launch until I close my Java program. Is it because that specific program is waiting for arguments or something wrong with my code?

```
@FXML
private void runWorldpac() {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\speedDIAL\\speedDIAL.exe");
        Process p = process.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

External application starts but won't allow any interaction with the original application until i close this external program. Tried running a new thread, same result.
Here's the new code:

```
try {
            ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\speedDIAL\\speedDIAL.exe");
            Map<String, String> environ = process.environment();
            Process p = process.start();
            InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(line);
            }
            System.out.println("Program terminated!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Where are you handling the streams that the process generates? That's one of the first things I'd do here, that and to make sure that my process runs in its own thread.

Comment: This external application is not supposed to send any data back to my application, do i still need to handle the streams? So i need to specify that it runs on another thread? I thought it was already doing that because when i close my app, the external application remains running(Actually starts running). Sorry i'm relatively new to this. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely need to handle streams, else the application risks running out of buffer memory potentially causing deadlock. Please read [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html). The article contains some dated information (not using ProcessBuilder for one), but much of the information that it contains is right on point.

Comment: Read that article, good info. Also read another good example on here. It's running in a new thread now, but my program is waiting for the external application to finish before it continues, I understand that's usually desired, but not in this case, how can i disable that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Read that article, good info. Also read another good example on here. It's running in a new thread now, but my program is waiting for the external application to finish before it continues, I understand that's usually desired, but not in this case, how can i disable that?

Wait for the production of the exit value in a new thread. Something like:

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\speedDIAL\\speedDIAL.exe");

    // don't forget to handle the error stream, and so 
    // either combine error stream with input stream, as shown here
    // or gobble it separately
    pBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true); 
    final Process process = pBuilder.start();
    final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

    // in case you need to send information back to the process
    // get its output stream. Don't forget to close when through with it
    final OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();

    // thread to handle or gobble text sent from input stream 
    new Thread(() -> {
        // try with resources
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // TODO: handle line
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();

    // thread to get exit value from process without blocking 
    Thread waitForThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            int exitValue = process.waitFor();
            // TODO: handle exit value here
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    waitForThread.start();

    // if you want to join after a certain time:
    long timeOut = 4000;
    waitForThread.join(timeOut);
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly, Comments are very helpful in explaining everything, so i need to create a different thread to handle the exit value if i don't want my program to wait correct?

Comment: @Karodarmoyan: yes